# Add data into table on button click

Tags: vb.net

I need lots of help with my VB betting app project. Right now I'm stuck on the syntax for a submit button that sends user input from the textboxes in the vb form to the ms access table.

This is my code:

```
private sub command1_Click() 
    Dim rs As Recordset set rs=currentdb.openrecordset("tblGame_information")  with rs .AddNew !awb=Me.txt_awb .Update 
    End With 
End Sub
```

And after that, clicking the add button the error message says:

> method or data member not found

The `Private Sub Command1_Click ()` is highlited yellow

Comment: private sub command1_Click()
Dim rs As Recordset
set rs=currentdb.openrecordset("tblGame_information")
with rs
.AddNew
!awb=Me.txt_awb
.Update
End With
End Sub

Comment: after clicking the add button the error message says method or data member not found and the Private Sub Command1_Click () is highlited yellow.

Answer (score 0):

sure textbox txt_awb in the form and the field awb in the table exists (typo)? Always use

```vb
    Option Explicit
```

on top of form or module (this prevents typing errors in identifiers).

Renamed Command1? Then you have to rename the click event too.